# Proper way to iterate over two dimensional json

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, array-map, for-of-loop

I have a two dimensional json that looks like:

```
[[{"ID":1,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:00:00"},
{"ID":2,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:01:00"}],
[{"ID":3,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:02:00"},
{"ID":4,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:03:00"}]]
```

It is serialized from C# object. Anyway I try to iterate over this json like:

```
for (var key in data) // first loop
{
  var item = data[key];
  for (var key2 in item) // second loop
  {
    // some code...
  }
}
```

Where the first loop should iterate two times: during first iteration the second loop should iterate over two objects with IDs 1 and 2; and during second iteration over objects with IDs 3 and 4.

I guess the problem is that first loop doesn't have Key because first loop iterates only one time and second loop iterates over objects with IDs 1,2,3,4.

How can I iterate over this as two dimensional tab then?

**[EDIT]**

I made a mistake during iterating inside second loop and it looked like it doesn't iterate. The solution above is correct.

Comment: What you do is correct in principle. Once you are in the innermost loop you should be able to access, e.g. the `ID` with value `2` as `item['key2'].ID`. Or are you trying to do something else? This, of course, assuming that you are talking about arrays and objects and not an actual json, that is a string.

Comment: I made a mistake. I forgot to increase iterator that was above first for loop (it was used in second loop) and it looked like it doesn't iterate. My bad sorry.

Answer (score 3):

For loop should work but you can also use maps/forEach/for-of to iterate over arrays:

```
var input = [
  [{"ID":1,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:00:00"},
    {"ID":2,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:01:00"}],
  [{"ID":3,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:02:00"},
   {"ID":4,"Name":"....","Ct":123, "Time":"2018-05-07T00:03:00"}]
];

input.map(outElem => {
  console.log('======== outter ========');
  outElem.map(inElem => {
    console.log('======== inner ========');
    console.log(inElem.ID);
  });
});

// Output:
======== outter ========
======== inner ========
1
======== inner ========
2
======== outter ========
======== inner ========
3
======== inner ========
4
```

Or forEach:

```
input.forEach(outElem => {
  console.log('======== outter ========');
  outElem.forEach(inElem => {
    console.log('======== inner ========');
    console.log(inElem.ID);
  });
});
```

Or for of:

```
for (const outElem of input) {
  console.log('======== outter ========');
  for (const inElem of outElem) {
    console.log('======== inner ========');
    console.log(inElem.ID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks better than two for loops and it's easier to refer to objects

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
 [{
   "ID": 1,
   "Name": "....",
   "Ct": 123,
   "Time": "2018-05-07T00:00:00"
  },
  {
   "ID": 2,
   "Name": "....",
   "Ct": 123,
   "Time": "2018-05-07T00:01:00"
  }
 ],
 [{
   "ID": 3,
   "Name": "....",
   "Ct": 123,
   "Time": "2018-05-07T00:02:00"
  },
  {
   "ID": 4,
   "Name": "....",
   "Ct": 123,
   "Time": "2018-05-07T00:03:00"
  }
 ]
];

for (var key in data) // first loop
{
  var item = data[key];
  console.log('======== outter ========');
  for (var key2 in item) // second loop
  {
      console.log('======== inner ========');
      console.log(item[key2].ID);

  }
}
```